# Why is $(\sqrt{x^2})$ equal to $|x|$

Tags: radicals, absolute-value

I don't understand why you have to write the absolute value sign when solving for the square root of $x$ squared.

Shouldn't the answer automatically be positive? Why is the absolute value sign needed?

Comment: The question as stated is ambiguous. Do you mean "Why is $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$?" or "Why is $\sqrt{x}^2=|x|$?" This is why using MathJax is good.

Comment: Long story short: because $\sqrt{(-5)^2}=5\ne -5$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sqrt{x^2}=\begin{cases}x & \text{if} \: x\geq0 \\ -x & \text{if} \: x<0  \end{cases} = |x|$$

Is it clear?

Comment: Downvoter, reason please? Do not go serial downvoting.. Give some reason..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the square root is automatically positive - that's exactly *why* we need the absolute value when we write $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. If instead we wrote $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ that would be wrong; for $x<0$ that would say the square root of $x^2$ was *not* positive.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is automatically positive, but $x$ in the radicand isn't necessarily.

*Another justification*:

Both are non-negative, and their squares are equal.