# How do you read $\pm ?$ Why does $|x|=3\implies x=\pm 3 ?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, absolute-value

**Question 1**

How is the symbol '±' read? "Plus AND Minus" or Plus OR Minus"? All this time I've been reading it as Plus-Minus. My math teacher says that it's the former; but then in $$x^2 = 9 \implies x= ± 3, $$ how does $x$ equal two values? $x$ should equal $+3$ OR $-3,$ right?

**Question 2**

My teacher says that $$|x| ≠ ± x\tag A$$ but that $$|x| = 5 \implies x = ±5.\tag B$$ Wait... what? What is going on here?

He also says that $$\sqrt{x^2}= |x|.$$ But this means that $$|3|=\sqrt{9} =3,$$ which, by $(\text B),$ implies that $$ |3| = ± 3;$$ doesn't this contradict $(\text A) ?$

Comment: *Basic Maths Doubts* is  an exceedingly poor title.  I have changed it for you this time. Next time, keep in mind that people who are looking for answers to the same question will be more likely to find your question if you title it usefully. Please do not use a title of the format "<adjective> maths questions/doubts/problems" ever again. Thanks.

Comment: You should ask other teacher next time.

Comment: @rschwieb Got it!

Answer (score 4):

1) Think of $x^2=9$ as having *two possible solutions*: $x=3$ or $x=-3$. You could also say that $x=3$ and $x=-3$ are valid solutions. This is more a matter of wording I think.

2) When the value of $x$ is known, we can either have $|x|=x$ or $|x|=-x$ *but not both*. Consider $x=-2$. Then $|-2| = 2 = -(-2)$. So here, we do have $|x|=-x$. But $|-2|=2 \neq -2$, i.e. $|x| \neq x$. For $x=2$ we have the cases switched around.

3) With regards to your edit, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1634717/252641) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1634717/252641).

Comment: From what I understand from your answer $±$ means plus OR minus right? So writing $|x|= ±x$ should be just fine, wouldn't you say?

Comment: If the value of $x$ is *known* I don't think it would be correct to write that because of the example in my answer.

Comment: @William  It is not acceptable to write $|x| = \pm x$ unless $x = 0$.  If $x > 0$, then $|x| = x$; if $x < 0$, then $|x| = -x$.

Comment: @William In case my posted answer is not visible enough: $$\forall x{\in}\mathbb R\:\: |x|=\pm x$$ is a mathematically *true* universally-quantified disjunction.

Answer (score 3):

The notation $±$ should be read plus *or* minus (at least, this is how it goes in French).

I don't know why your maths teacher would say otherwise.

Generally speaking, this is a shortcut to avoid writing two different expressions that are identic up to a sign. You can avoid it by writing both, and connecting them with an *"or"*.

(NB: there is absolutely no maths in there, only notational convention, or even notational abuse.)

Comment: It's also "plus or minus" in English, at least, in my experience. I haven't come across anyone who calls it "plus minus" before.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol $\pm$ should be read plus or minus.

**Background**

By convention, if $x \geq 0$, then $\sqrt{x}$ is the principal square root of $x$, meaning the nonnegative square root of $x$.  Hence, $\sqrt{9} = 3$.  If we want to denote the negative square root, we write $-\sqrt{x}$.  Thus, the negative square root of $9$ is expressed in the form $-\sqrt{9} = -3$.  Notice that the principal square root of a number is uniquely defined.

The absolute value of a real number $x$, denoted $|x|$, is its distance from $0$ on the real number line.  Since distances are nonnegative, the absolute value of a number is never negative.  If $x \geq 0$, then $|x| = x$.  For instance, $|5| = 5$ since $5$ is five units from $0$ and $|0| = 0$ since $0$ is zero units from $0$.  If $x < 0$, then $|x| = -x$.  For instance, $|-4| = 4$ since $-4$ is four units from $0$.  Consequently, we can write a piecewise definition of the absolute value as follows:
$$|x| = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if $x \geq 0$}\\
-x & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}$$
Observe that
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{5^2} & = \sqrt{25} = 5 = |5|\\
\sqrt{0^2} & = \sqrt{0} = 0 = |0|\\
\sqrt{(-4)^2} & = \sqrt{16} = 4 = -(-4) = |-4|
\end{align*}
Observe that if $x \geq 0$, then $\sqrt{x^2} = x = |x|$.  If $x < 0$, then $\sqrt{x^2} = -x = |x|$.  Therefore, we obtain the alternative definition of absolute value:
$$\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$$

> Solve the equation $x^2 = 9$.

\begin{align*}
x^2 & = 9\\
\sqrt{x^2} & = \sqrt{9} && \text{take the principal square root of each side of the equation}\\
|x| & = 3 && \text{evaluate the principal square roots}
\end{align*}
The equation $|x| = 3$ means that $x$ is a real number whose distance from $0$ on the real number line is $3$.  There are two such numbers.  They are $3$ and $-3$.  However, $x$ cannot simultaneously be both $3$ and $-3$.  Hence, we say that $x = 3$ or $-3$.  Our solution set is $S = \{3, -3\}$.  Thus, this equation has two distinct solutions that happen to be opposite in sign.  When this occurs, the solution is sometimes expressed in the form
$$x = \pm 3$$
to indicate that if $x$ is a solution of the equation, then $x = 3$ or $x = -3$.  To put is another way, either $3$ or $-3$ could be substituted for $x$ to make the equation $x^2 = 9$ true.

Clearly, it does not make sense to say $x = 3$ and $x = -3$ since $3 \neq -3$.  Consequently, it also does not make sense to read the symbol $\pm$ as plus and minus.

The symbol $\pm$ indicates that the symbol may be substituted by either the positive or negative values of the variable (see [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus%E2%80%93minus_sign)).  Therefore, it does not make sense to write
$$|x| = \pm x$$
since there is only a single value which may be substituted for $|x|$.  If $x \geq 0$, that value is $x$; if $x < 0$, that value is $-x$.

Comment: Your last paragraphs appear to be very confusing. "We cannot write $|x|= ±x$", likewise we cannot write $|3|=±3$. Okay but why not? Like you say, $±$ means "plus OR minus", I'm not insisting minus 3 is an answer but rather either of $3$ OR $-3$. So logically, it should be valid.

Comment: @William Good catch.  Thank you.

Comment: Your agreement to my comment has inspired me to ask [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4230273/552998) Maybe you can share your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 0):

- $ \pm $ is pronounced as plus or minus
- $x=|4| \implies x=4,-4$ because both $|4|$ and $|-4|$ are equal to $4$

Answer (score 0):

This answer is concerned with real numbers only.

1. > How is the symbol '±' read?

   The **notational shorthand** $$y=\pm x,$$ that is, $$\text{“$y$ equals plus }\textit{or}\text{ minus $x$”,}$$ is **definitionally equivalent** to $$y\in\{x,-x\}.$$
2. > $|x| = 5 \implies x = ±5$

   True; in fact, $$|x| = 5 \iff x = ±5,\tag0$$ since for each $x,$ each side of the biconditional means precisely that $x$ is an element of $\{-5,5\}.$

   > $ |3| = ± 3$

   True; indeed, $|3|\in\{-3,3\}.$

   > $|x| ≠ ± x$

   False; $$\text{for each }x,\:\:|x|=\pm x.\quad\quad\Large✓\tag1$$
3. The `±` notational shorthand makes statement $(1)$ look like a [mathematical identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254850/21813), $|x|\equiv\pm x,$ and misleadingly suggest that $|x|$ and $\pm x$ are mutually substitutable, when in fact $$|x|\not\equiv\pm x.\quad\quad\Large✓\tag2$$ To be clear: **$\boldsymbol{|x|=\pm x}$ is not a genuine equation**, and statement $(1)$ means: $$\text{for each }x,\:\:|x|\in \{x,-x\}\tag1$$
   $$\text{for each }x,\;\big(\,|x|=x\quad\textit{or}\quad |x|=-x\,\big).\tag1$$
4. Observe that $$\boxed{\;y=|x|\quad \iff\quad y=\pm x\:\:\:\textit{and}\:\:\:y\ge0\;};$$ this result entails statements $(0)$ and $(2).$

   [Hence](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a9urcxfmle), \begin{align}& x\in\{-4,-2,0\}\\\iff {}& x^2+3x=\pm x \\\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies{}& \color{brown}{x^2+3x=|x|}\\\iff{}& x^2+3x=\pm x \:\:\:\textit{and}\:\:\:x^2+3x \ge0
   \\\iff{}& x\in\{-4,0\}.\end{align}